# How to replace values in a dataframe with values in another dataframe based on certain condition?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace the values of columns "q1_body" and "q2_body" of dataframe "result" with the values of "body" of the same id in dataframe "df", and the code is like:

```
def replace_body(x):
    id1 = result.loc[x].qid1
    result.loc[x].q1_body = df[df["qid"]==id1]["body"]
    id2 = result.loc[x].qid2
    result.loc[x].q2_body = df[df["qid"]==id2]["body"]

result.index.map(lambda x: replace_body(x))
```

When I run the code I got the following reminder in my ipython console and the program just stuck here:

> //anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py:3110:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:
>   A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
>             self[name] = value

Hope anyone can tell me what is wrong here.

Suppose the two dataframe are:

result:

```
qid1 q1_body qid2 q2_body
 1a    abc    2a    bcd
 1a    abc    3a    cde
 2a    bcd    3a    cde
```

df:

```
qid body
1a sfgaks
2a shdfjk
3a adjkwf
```

And the expected output is like:

result:

```
qid1 q1_body qid2 q2_body
 1a  sfgaks   2a  shdfjk
 1a  sfgaks   3a  adjkwf
 2a  shdfjk   3a  adjkwf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
s = df.set_index('qid')['body']
result['q1_body'] = result['qid1'].map(s)
result['q2_body'] = result['qid2'].map(s)
print (result)
  qid1 q1_body qid2 q2_body
0   1a  sfgaks   2a  shdfjk
1   1a  sfgaks   3a  adjkwf
2   2a  shdfjk   3a  adjkwf
```

Comment: Why map? `loc` would do, as I have written in my answer. Only thing, I forgot to set the index on `df`... Oops! :-P

Comment: `map` is better and more obvious way for mapping data.

Comment: Slower than `.loc`. Let's do a time test, shall we?

Comment: Need to edit it. I forgot so many things about Pandas. Not been using it, these days.

Comment: Yes, and dont forget add output to your answer.

Comment: Done, see my answer. Much has changed. `map` is faster now. I remember last year `map` had a loop internally, which was slower than `loc`. I answered a similar question at some point, with piRSquared, if I remember, and he used `loc` which was much faster.

Comment: I tried your solution, however, in the output all the values of q1_body and q2_body are NaN.

Comment: I think there is problem different dtypes - e.g. one values are strings and another are ints. What is `print (df.dtypes)` and `print (result.dtypes)` ? For same `dtypes` need e.g. `result['qid1'] = result['qid1'].astype(str)` and `df['qid'] = df['qid'].astype(str)`

Comment: You are right, I got the correct output after executing " df['body'] = df['body'].astype(str)" . Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
# Set index and get body as a series
s = df.set_index(qid)['body']
result['q1_body'] = s.loc[result['qid1']].values
result['q2_body'] = s.loc[result['qid2']].values
```

Result:

```
  qid1 q1_body qid2 q2_body
0   1a  sfgaks   2a  shdfjk
1   1a  sfgaks   3a  adjkwf
2   2a  shdfjk   3a  adjkwf
```

---

Timing (10k rows, using auto-generated Lorem):

My method
[image: My method]

@Jezareal's method
[image: @Jezreal's Method]

Comment: Thank you. I tried your solution but got this error: "KeyError: 'None of [0    1\n1    1\n2    2\nName: qid1, dtype: object] are in the [index]'"